# I cant render this Grid

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I'm trying to create my first 3d model with material . so i pick up my radio to be my guide . There is a problem that i cant solve . i tried to create a grid in front of the radio but when i render it for testing i cant see that grid 
[image]

and im not sure i did the right way to create this grid . I just use plane and then subdivide it 10 time twice ! and then use wireframe modifier to create tiny hold in the grid  AM i doing it right ? Plz give me some advice Thx you :)

Comment: Can you see the little camera right to the object grid in the outline view. Click to re-enable render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click this button:
[image]
The if the little camera is grayed out, it means that the object is not visible in the render
If the eye is grayed out, it means that the object is not visible in the preview

Comment: Woah !! i didnt notice it was disabled :P Thx by the way